# Form still submitting when required fields not filled out

Tags: php, css

My contact form is suppose to require certain fields to be filled in or it will give you an error on the fields required to be filled in before it submits the form and redirects you to the thank you page. It is not working and I am a newbie coder so I am not sure on how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks and have a great day..

```js
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "hello@capebretonstartpage.com";
    $email_subject = "Comment on CapeBretonStartPage";
 header("Location: https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/thank-you/");
 
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.</br></br>";
        echo $error."</br></br>";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.</br></br>";
        die();
    }
 
 
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
 
     
 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
 
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
 if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Subject you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
  
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
 
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

```css
form {
margin-top: 50px;
}

input[type=text] {
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

input:focus {
border: 1px solid #196477;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
outline: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea {
border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;
margin: 8px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 12px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}

textarea:focus {
border: 1px solid #196477;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
outline: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background-color: #8dc63f;  
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;    
border-radius: 5px;
border-right-style: none;   
border-top-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box; 
color: #ffffff; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
opacity: 1.0;
outline: none;
padding: 10px;  
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;   
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
background-color: #8dc63f;    
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none; 
border-radius: 5px;
border-right-style: none;
border-top-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box; 
color: #ffffff;  
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 600;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
opacity: 0.9;
padding: 10px;    
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
<label for="first_name">First Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="last_name">Last Name: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="email">Email: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"/>
</br></br>
<label for="subject">Subject: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" autocomplete="off"/>
</br>
</br>
<label for="comments">Comments: <font color="red">*</font></label>
</br>
<textarea name="comments" cols="50" rows="8" id="comments" autocomplete="off"/></textarea>
</br>
</br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: FYI `<font>` tag has been deprecated for ages. Do not use it.

Comment: I see nothing preventing the form from being submitted in the HTML. Your PHP code appears to set the redirect before it checks to see if it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is being performed in the PHP code that is executed by the web-server upon receipt of the form submission, so no code here can affect the submission of the form.

> ...before it submits the form and redirects you to the thank you page

Instead you need to perform the validation in the page that contains the form to be submitted. There are a couple of ways to achieve this, the simplest being the inclusion of the "required" attribute in input controls. This will prevent the form submission if the control does not have a value.

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Comment: ... or a valid value, so if an email doesn't have an @ symbol it will be invalid and if a phone number is a word it will also be invalid :)

Answer (score 0):

put header end of your php code

```
 header("Location: https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/thank-you/");
}
```

you can get full code here https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b1Gy

Answer (score 0):

```
I have seen that you used '!isset' for checking empty string, but isset() return false for "" as it checking for null value only. So along with isset() we can use empty() function or  we just check empty function.

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "hello@capebretonstartpage.com";
    $email_subject = "Comment on CapeBretonStartPage";
 header("Location: https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/thank-you/");
 
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.</br></br>";
        echo $error."</br></br>";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.</br></br>";
        die();
    }
 
 
    // validation expected data exists
    if(empty($_POST['first_name']) ||
        empty($_POST['last_name']) ||
        empty($_POST['subject']) ||
        empty($_POST['email']) ||
        empty($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
 
     
 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
 
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
 if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Subject you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
  
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.</br>';
  }
 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
 
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```